# Parse Open Source server on heroku throwing memory quota exceeded

Tags: heroku, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am running a parse server on heroku with Mlab.[image]

When I running a search query on a table (Who have 188K records),I am receiving below error:

```
    Process running mem=558M(109.2%) 
    2019-11-18T18:16:48.355162+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
```

I tried to run server via `node --max-old-space-size=4096 parse/server.js` but still the issue not resolved.

Please advise an solution.

Comment: look at adding an index to improve query performance : https://docs.mlab.com/indexing

Comment: Since I don't know node I can judge what needs to change there, but some points that can help: how big is the result you are querying? are you selecting the whole table? You shouldn't select all, only the results you need. 

About heroku: The message "Memory quota exceeded" only means your dyno is swapping, which means your app will become slower. When "memory quota vastly exceeded" pops up, your dyno will be restartet, which cancels your request. And if you need the memory, upgrade the dyno to 2x or bigger